# How to create a gauge using Kivy?

Tags: python, android, user-interface, kivy, speed-test

I want to make an internet speed test application for Android with Python.
I have done the back-end side but I have a hard time with the front-end.
After research, I decided to use the Kivy framework, however, I need guidance on how to create a gauge like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to create a gauge. The first one involves using code with mathematics, while the second one involves using graphic files for the dial (cadran) and needle. Below, you will find the implementation of the second way, with the help of the original code of the [gauge widget](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.gauge) from the [Kivy Garden project](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.10.1/api-kivy.garden.html), in which you will be able to understand how the gauge works more easily.

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import BoundedNumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath


class Gauge(Widget):
    '''
    Gauge class
    '''

    unit = NumericProperty(1.8)
    value = BoundedNumericProperty(0, min=0, max=100, errorvalue=0)
    path = dirname(abspath(__file__))
    file_gauge = StringProperty(join(path, "cadran.png"))
    file_needle = StringProperty(join(path, "needle.png"))
    size_gauge = BoundedNumericProperty(128, min=128, max=256, errorvalue=128)
    size_text = NumericProperty(10)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Gauge, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self._gauge = Scatter(
            size=(self.size_gauge, self.size_gauge),
            do_rotation=False,
            do_scale=False,
            do_translation=False
        )

        _img_gauge = Image(
            source=self.file_gauge,
            size=(self.size_gauge, self.size_gauge)
        )

        self._needle = Scatter(
            size=(self.size_gauge, self.size_gauge),
            do_rotation=False,
            do_scale=False,
            do_translation=False
        )

        _img_needle = Image(
            source=self.file_needle,
            size=(self.size_gauge, self.size_gauge)
        )

        self._glab = Label(font_size=self.size_text, markup=True)
        self._progress = ProgressBar(max=100, height=20, value=self.value)

        self._gauge.add_widget(_img_gauge)
        self._needle.add_widget(_img_needle)

        self.add_widget(self._gauge)
        self.add_widget(self._needle)
        self.add_widget(self._glab)
        self.add_widget(self._progress)

        self.bind(pos=self._update)
        self.bind(size=self._update)
        self.bind(value=self._turn)

    def _update(self, *args):
        '''
        Update gauge and needle positions after sizing or positioning.
        '''
        self._gauge.pos = self.pos
        self._needle.pos = (self.x, self.y)
        self._needle.center = self._gauge.center
        self._glab.center_x = self._gauge.center_x
        self._glab.center_y = self._gauge.center_y + (self.size_gauge / 4)
        self._progress.x = self._gauge.x
        self._progress.y = self._gauge.y + (self.size_gauge / 4)
        self._progress.width = self.size_gauge

    def _turn(self, *args):
        '''
        Turn needle, 1 degree = 1 unit, 0 degree point start on 50 value.
        '''
        self._needle.center_x = self._gauge.center_x
        self._needle.center_y = self._gauge.center_y
        self._needle.rotation = (50 * self.unit) - (self.value * self.unit)
        self._glab.text = "[b]{0:.0f}[/b]".format(self.value)
        self._progress.value = self.value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.uix.slider import Slider


    class GaugeApp(App):
        increasing = NumericProperty(1)
        begin = NumericProperty(50)
        step = NumericProperty(1)

        def build(self):
            box = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', padding=5)
            self.gauge = Gauge(value=50, size_gauge=256, size_text=25)
            self.slider = Slider(orientation='vertical')

            stepper = Slider(min=1, max=25)
            stepper.bind(
                value=lambda instance, value: setattr(self, 'step', value)
            )

            box.add_widget(self.gauge)
            box.add_widget(stepper)
            box.add_widget(self.slider)
            Clock.schedule_interval(lambda *t: self.gauge_increment(), 0.03)
            return box

        def gauge_increment(self):
            begin = self.begin
            begin += self.step * self.increasing
            if 0 < begin < 100:
                self.gauge.value = self.slider.value = begin
            else:
                self.increasing *= -1
            self.begin = begin


    GaugeApp().run()
```

Of course, if you don't want to use the default dial ([cadran](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.gauge/blob/master/cadran.png)) and [needle](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.gauge/blob/master/needle.png), you will have to design your own using a [vector graphics editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics_editor).